# How to call user control's(.ascx) method in .aspx page

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, user-controls, webforms

I have created user control, in that user control i have one method and I want to call this method in .aspx. I have registered this user control in aspx

For example:
Below is method in user control.

```
public void SetGridData()
{
}
```

I want to call above method in .aspx.cs file.
How can we call this method?

Comment: You're opening a can of worms.  What exactly is this method being used for?  The reason I ask is that it's not returning anything, and, by the method name, it seems to be used to update a grid in the control with data.  The problem is that if you invoke this in the aspx, it's probably not going to occur when you want it to - that is, at render time.  We probably need a little more information about what you're trying to do.

Comment: @matt I have not pasted here all the code for SetGridData() method.

Comment: I understand that.  What I'm saying is that if you invoke this method in your ascx file, it is going to occur in the render stage.  Take a look at the aspx page life cycle to understand why you probably don't want to do this: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178472.ASPX  Render occurs _after_ Page_Load and Page_Init.

Comment: @matt, it's just an example, I have to call X Method of User control in to .aspx.cs file.

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere in the ASPX page's code you should have a reference to the user control object.  For example, if the user control is called `MyUserControl` then somewhere at the class level for the page (possibly in a separate partial class designer file) should be:

```
protected MyUserControl myUserControl1;
```

or something similar to that.  That's the instance of the user control for the page's class.  The page life cycle should instantiate it by the time `Page_Load` is reached, so from then on you can use that object:

```
myUserControl1.SetGridData();
```

Comment: Is it possible to use and call the method/function of usercontrol before Page_load of aspx page?

Comment: @user35: That depends on what you need to be available in the page/control when calling the method.  The object itself is initialized early in the page life cycle, but certain page life cycle events may not have been invoked: http://stackoverflow.com/a/7335271/328193

Answer (score 1):

If this is purely an example, then you can call methods in codefiles with the following syntax:

```
<%= SetGridData(); %>
```

However, just be aware of the notes I put in the comments above.