# How to pass value from user control to aspx page on pageload?

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, get, set

The scenario is very simple. I have an aspx page with a user control. I want to set a value and get a response  from usercontrol on aspx page's pageload. The SET job is done, but can't GET the response. It's always empty. I tried two methods, but none of them worked.

ASPX PAGE

```
<uc1:ucContent ID="Content1" runat="server" />
```

CODE BEHIND

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // SET job is working without any problem
    Content1.ItemName = "X";

    //METHOD ONE:
    Page.Title = Content1.MetaPageTitle;

    //METHOD TWO:
    HiddenField hdnPageTitle = (HiddenField)Content1.FindControl("hdnMetaPageTitle");
    Page.Title = hdnPageTitle.Value;
}
```

USER CONTROL

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemName))
    {
         // GET DATA FROM DB

         // METHOD ONE:
         hdnTitle.Value = DB.DATA;

         // METHOD TWO:
         metaPageTitle = DB.DATA;
    }
}

private string metaPageTitle;
public string MetaPageTitle
{
    // METHOD ONE:
    get { return metaPageTitle; }

    // METHOD TWO:
    get { return hdnTitle.value; }
}
```

**EDIT**

itemName is a UserControl property to get a value from Parent Page:

```
private string itemName;
public string ItemName
{
    set { itemName = value; }
}
```

Thanks for your kind help in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the problem is that the `page`'s `Page_Load` is triggered before the `UserControl`(Have a look: [asp.net: what's the page life cycle order of a control/page compared to a user contorl inside it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7335142/asp-net-whats-the-page-life-cycle-order-of-a-control-page-compared-to-a-user-c)).

So you could set the property in `Page_init`:

In your `UserControl`:

```
protected void Page_Init(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(itemName))
    {
         // GET DATA FROM DB

         hdnTitle.Value = DB.DATA;
    }
}
```

Now this should work in your page's `Page_Load`:

```
Page.Title = Content1.MetaPageTitle;
```

Normally i would prefer another kind of communication between a Page and a UserControl. It's called event-driven communication and means that you should trigger a custom event in your UC when the `MetaPageTitle` changed (so in the appopriate event-handler).

Then the page can handle this specific event and react accordingly.

[Mastering Page-UserControl Communication - event driven communication](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/8797/Mastering-Page-UserControl-Communication#4.3)

Comment: Thanks for answer! Now the problem is I can't get values in User Control side. I mean "itemName" is always empty.

Comment: I have no idea what `itemName` is, you haven't shown it.

Comment: @Kardo: then provide a method `SetItemName` which sets this property and stores it somewhere(f.e. in ViewState,HiddenField,Session). In this method you should call your `// GET DATA FROM DB`-logic.